# jQuery :icontains selector string with wildcard char

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, wildcard

I use the code under to get back all elements that contains a specific string:

```
specString="a b";
a.schHits=$('*:icontains("'+specString+'")');
```

html exempel:

```
<body>
 <label>a b</label>
 <label>a_b</label>
</body>
```

resulting selected element:

```
"<label>a b</label>"
```

now to the question: is there a way to use icontains (or equal in speed) function/selector with a wildcard char? like this exempel:

```
specString="a*b"; or specString="a%b";
a.schHits=$('*:icontains("'+specString+'")');
```

html exempel:

```
<body>
 <label>a b</label>
 <label>a_b</label>
</body>
```

resulting selected element:

```
"<label>a b</label>","<label>a_b</label>"
```

icontains, https://gist.github.com/pklauzinski/b6f836f99cfa11100488

```
$.expr[':'].icontains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(text) {
    return function(e) {
        return $(e).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(text.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

I have been looking for a way for days and hope someone will help.

Comment: Are you share `icontains` selector? I think it should be `contains`.

Comment: There is no `icontains` listed in [docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/content-filter-selector/). Is it something custom?

Comment: yes i forgot that... https://gist.github.com/pklauzinski/b6f836f99cfa11100488

Comment: you can't use `icontains` as it use raw `text` to check with `indexOf`. you need to use another method.

Comment: And thats whats i have been looking for for days with no result...

Comment: So, to get this straight: You have the one-line implementation of the selector right before your eyes _for days_ and ask then, what it can do? OK, I’ll bite: http://jsfiddle.net/boldewyn/bcLyf0o8/ But be warned, it is less performing than a simple string search. Perhaps you’ll find it more worthwhile to pack this fuzzy search implementation in a selector: https://github.com/bevacqua/fuzzysearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this after Boldewyn gave me his comment and it works...

```
$.expr[":"].xcontains=$.expr.createPseudo(function(arg){
    arg=arg.replace(/([\.\+\?\^\$\\])/g,'\$1').replace(/[*%]/g,'.*');
    var prex=new RegExp(arg,'i');
    return function(elem){
        return jQuery(elem).text().search(prex)>=0;
    };
});
```

but if any of you think of **any** preformance tweeks plz tell me... any suggestions is welcome

thx u Boldewyn =)